# Run same code after install application

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, installation

My app before first run need execute same code. Is possible move this to installer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. iOS apps are installed with Apple's App Store installation process. Apple does not offer any hooks into the installation process to inject code. The app will have to execute this first run code at first run.

If this first run work is significant, and you want to move the work to the install process because it blocks the UI during first run, you can do some things to alleviate the problem. First, you can put this code on its own thread, and let the main thread start the UI. You can then jump to asking for the user to enter settings, or go through help screens explaining the program.  While the user is working through these tasks with low computing resource demands, the higher demand setup thread may have plenty of time to do the first run work.